# HTTPModule Event Execution Order?

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule, httpapplication

Does anyone know of a site or page, or know the order of execution for the events of the HTTPApplication class for HTTPModule event execution?

I found the [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication_events.aspx) for all of the events, but it doesn't show a list of process steps and I haven't been able to find one.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Maybe this helps

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307985/en-us/

> An HttpApplication class provides a number of events with which modules can synchronize. The following events are available for modules to synchronize with on each request. These events are listed in sequential order:

1. BeginRequest
2. AuthenticateRequest
3. AuthorizeRequest
4. ResolveRequestCache
5. AcquireRequestState
6. PreRequestHandlerExecute
7. PostRequestHandlerExecute
8. ReleaseRequestState
9. UpdateRequestCache
10. EndRequest

> The following events are available for modules to synchronize with for each request transmission. The order of these events is non-deterministic.

- PreSendRequestHeaders
- PreSendRequestContent
- Error

See the article for full info.

Answer (score 52):

MSDN Library documentation:

- [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 5.0 and 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)

Here are the events (in bold) and other steps in the request pipeline for ASP.NET 4.0:

> 1. Validate the request, which examines the information sent by the browser and determines whether it contains potentially malicious markup.
> 2. Perform URL mapping, if any URLs have been configured in the UrlMappingsSection section of the Web.config file.
> 3. Raise the **BeginRequest** event.
> 4. Raise the **AuthenticateRequest** event.
> 5. Raise the **PostAuthenticateRequest** event.
> 6. Raise the **AuthorizeRequest** event.
> 7. Raise the **PostAuthorizeRequest** event.
> 8. Raise the **ResolveRequestCache** event.
> 9. Raise the **PostResolveRequestCache** event.
> 10. **[IIS 5.0/6.0]** Based on the file name extension of the requested resource (mapped in the application's configuration file), select a class that implements IHttpHandler to process the request. If the request is for an object (page) derived from the Page class and the page needs to be compiled, ASP.NET compiles the page before creating an instance of it. **[IIS 7.0]** Raise the **MapRequestHandler** event. An appropriate handler is selected based on the file name extension of the requested resource. The handler can be a native-code module such as the IIS 7.0 StaticFileModule or a managed-code module such as the PageHandlerFactory class (which handles .aspx files).
> 11. Raise the **PostMapRequestHandler** event.
> 12. Raise the **AcquireRequestState** event.
> 13. Raise the **PostAcquireRequestState** event.
> 14. Raise the **PreRequestHandlerExecute** event.
> 15. Call the ProcessRequest method (or the asynchronous version IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest) of the appropriate IHttpHandler class for the request. For example, if the request is for a page, the current page instance handles the request.
> 16. Raise the **PostRequestHandlerExecute** event.
> 17. Raise the **ReleaseRequestState** event.
> 18. Raise the **PostReleaseRequestState** event.
> 19. Perform response filtering if the Filter property is defined.
> 20. Raise the **UpdateRequestCache** event.
> 21. Raise the **PostUpdateRequestCache** event.
> 22. **[IIS 7.0]** Raise the **LogRequest** event.
> 23. **[IIS 7.0]** Raise the **PostLogRequest** event.
> 24. Raise the **EndRequest** event.
> 25. Raise the **PreSendRequestHeaders** event.
> 26. Raise the **PreSendRequestContent** event.
>
> Note: The MapRequestHandler, LogRequest, and PostLogRequest events are supported only if the application is running in Integrated mode in IIS 7.0 and with the .NET Framework 3.0 or later.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is out-of-date. Here is the list of events in the order they are raised according to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpapplication?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks):

> 1. BeginRequest
> 2. AuthenticateRequest
> 3. PostAuthenticateRequest
> 4. AuthorizeRequest
> 5. PostAuthorizeRequest
> 6. ResolveRequestCache
> 7. PostResolveRequestCache
>
>    After the PostResolveRequestCache event and before the PostMapRequestHandler event, an event handler (which is a page that corresponds to the request URL) is created. When a server is running IIS 7.0 in Integrated mode and at least the .NET Framework version 3.0, the MapRequestHandler event is raised. When a server is running IIS 7.0 in Classic mode or an earlier version of IIS, this event cannot be handled.
> 8. PostMapRequestHandler
> 9. AcquireRequestState
> 10. PostAcquireRequestState
> 11. PreRequestHandlerExecute
> 12. PostRequestHandlerExecute
> 13. ReleaseRequestState
> 14. PostReleaseRequestState
> 15. UpdateRequestCache
> 16. PostUpdateRequestCache
> 17. LogRequest
> 18. PostLogRequest
> 19. EndRequest