# Pre-Existing Script Injection Point

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httpmodule

I saw [this quote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx):

> **ASP.NET uses modules to implement** various application features, which
>   includes forms authentication, caching, session state, and **client
>   script services**.

I'd like to know precisely which module it refers to regarding the "client script services," and I'd like to know if the "client script services" can be configured to inject my own scripts.  If it can, then I won't bother to [make my own HttpModule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/793331/284758).

Please assume I'm using IIS7 integrated mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It refers to the [ScriptModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.handlers.scriptmodule.aspx). And to answer your second question about whether it can be configured to inject your own scripts, the answer is no, it can't.

There are other ways to inject your own scripts depending on what you are trying to achieve.