# Create Handler that manipulates head tag

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there any way to create a handler that changes the head tag content 
real time?

Comment: Probably your question is too broad. I could imagine writing a handler for the asp.net pipe. But on the other hand using a master page would be easier...

Comment: Yes, I saw some examples of handlers with master page...but unfortunately in project there is no master page & it is web app.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom HTTP Module:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227673.aspx

Here's an example of how to add a script to the head of each page:

[How2: what event to hook in HttpModule for putting js links into head element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792851/how2-what-event-to-hook-in-httpmodule-for-putting-js-links-into-head-element)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `HtmlGenericControl Server Control` for this purpose.

**HtmlGenericControl Server Control** 
Creates a server-side control that maps to an HTML element not represented by a specific .NET Framework class, such as  `<body> and <div>`.

Try Below one.

```
var h1 = new HtmlGenericControl("h1");
h1.InnerHtml = "Your header content";
```

For more information check [**HtmlGenericControl Server Control Declarative Syntax**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I hope this will help to you.