# IIS7 ISAPI Filter Module & HttpModule Events - How do they line up?

Tags: iis-7, httpmodule, isapi, integrated-pipeline-mode

So IIS7 in Integrated Pipeline mode uses a IsapiFilterModule to shim ISAPI filter DLL's and fire off the correct "events" on the filters, which is quite different than previous versions of IIS or IIS7 in classic mode because this means that HttpModules fire off right along side ISAPI filters in Integrated Pipeline mode.

So does anyone happen to know how ISAPI events (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524855.aspx) and the HttpModule events (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998536.aspx) line up?

Answer (score 0):

HttpModule events are fired after other filters, according to the MSDN:

> At this point, IIS begins processing the substance of the request. This can be done by an ISAPI extension, a CGI application, a script engine such as ASP or PERL, or by IIS itself for static files.

Order of the http module events you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441421/httpmodule-event-execution-order) or [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307985/en-us/)