# IIS7 HttpModule and ISAPI Filter execution order

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httpmodule, isapi

I have a site using [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) as well as a custom HttpModule that both do Url redirects and rewrites.

In IIS 6, everything worked fine: The ISAPI Rewrite filter would run first, followed by the HttpModule. In IIS 7 (Integrated mode) the order is now the reverse, which poses a problem.

My problem, specifically, is that the HttpModule has a condition where it will issue a Url rewrite using `context.RewritePath`. It will explicitly add "index.aspx" to the path if no document was provided, so a request to `/test/` gets rewritten to `/test/index.aspx`.

At some point after the path is rewritten, the ISAPI Rewrite filter executes. We've got a rule that does the opposite of the module: a request to `/test/index.aspx` gets 301-redirected to `/test/`. Thus, we have an endless loop.

**How is the execution order of HttpModules and ISAPI Filters determined in IIS 7?** Can the order be changed? I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474358), but it didn't really help. I'm not a master of IIS 7, but I do understand to some extent that modules and ISAPI filters run "together". Unfortunately, they are still administered differently and I can't figure out how to force one to run before the other. Help!

Note: let's assume I cannot change the existing code. It worked in IIS 6. I just want to know if there's a way to make it work in IIS 7 Integrated mode.

Answer (score 3):

I've also had a similar problem where I thought that ISAPI rewrites get executed first, but apparently that's not how things work with IIS7

I found this thread that states

> In integrated mode the events for native module, isapi and .net are called mixed together
>
> e.g. if it's a BeginRequest then the native module is the first to come, then isapi, then .net code. After that everything will repeat for AuthenticateRequest...
>
> Some time ago it used to be like this: isapi has processed all events, and only after that .net was invoked. This is probably what you've assumed.

http://www.helicontech.com/forum/18447-ISAPI_RW3_Lite_on_IIS_7x_Integrated_mode.html

Hopefully it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following article which explains the [IIS 7 pipeline](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tmarq/archive/2007/08/30/iis-7-0-asp-net-pipelines-modules-handlers-and-preconditions.aspx).  The order of the pipeline cannot be changed.  Not sure if this is an option or not, but you could potentially replace the ISAPI Rewrite with the [IIS URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite).  This may allow your application to run in the integrated pipeline mode, otherwise, you may need to switch your app pool to run in classic mode.