# Allow iframe from single route in flask using talisman

Tags: python, flask, iframe

I am using Flask with Flask-Talisman. My CSP is configured currently, for all routes as:

```
SELF = '\'self\''
csp = {
    'default-src': [SELF, '*.gstatic.com'],
    'connect-src': [SELF, 'https://fonts.googleapis.com', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com'],
    'frame-src': [SELF, 'https://js.stripe.com'],
    'script-src': [SELF, 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com', 'https://js.stripe.com', 'https://www.googletagmanager.com'],
    'style-src': [SELF, 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com', '\'unsafe-inline\''],
    'img-src': [SELF, '*', 'blob:', 'data:']
}
talisman.init_app(app, content_security_policy=csp, content_security_policy_nonce_in=['script-src'])
```

Whenever an external site tries to load my pages via `iframe` they receive the error `X-Frame-Options is SAMEORIGIN`, which is generally OK.

**However I would like a single route to be accessible** by external iframes on load. To achieve this I have followed the advice to set:

```
@talisman(frame_options=ALLOW_FROM, frame_options_allow_from='*')
```

before my specific route.

However **Chrome** does not allow this and reports an error. I beleive instead the CSP should instead be set. How should I re-write or re-configure my route to allow it to be accessed by external iframes in all browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Example on the flask-talisman route:

```
# Example of a route-specific talisman configuration

@app.route('/embeddable')
@talisman(

    frame_options='ALLOW-FROM',
    frame_options_allow_from='https://example.com/',

)

def embeddable():
    return "<html>I can be embedded.</html>"
```

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/flask-talisman/blob/master/example_app/main.py

Comment: I believe I can achieve this in my current setup replacing `'*'`, however Chrome does not allow `ALLOW FROM` so the solution is to affect `frame-ancestors` directly in the CSP set by talisman I think. i just dont know how to isolate it to a single route

Comment: I edited my answer after a made better research, give it a try, and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, perhaps my post was poorly written - I can already do exactly what you have answered, and my question is related to firefox and chrome not permiiting `ALLOW FROM`. see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658435/x-frame-options-allow-from-in-firefox-and-chrome. I seek an alternative solution that involves editing the CSP for single routes.

Comment: @J.Timm can you please assist with a way to do this but for a whole flask blueprint?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to augment my csp directly on the route with a `frame-ancestors` header than takes precedence in some browsers (inc chrome).

```
# assume a csp dict exists
@talisman(frame_options=ALLOW_FROM,
          frame_options_allow_from='*',
          content_security_policy={**csp, 'frame-ancestors': ['*']})
def flask_route():
    # individualised route
```