# How to "allow-from" more than one domain for "X-Frame-Options" in Rails 4 controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, ruby-on-rails-4, http-headers, x-frame-options

In a Ruby on Rails 4 application I'm working on, I need to make a page that will be pulled into an iframe hosted on the `foo.bar.com` server, so I have this controller method:

```
def iframed_page
  response.headers["X-FRAME-OPTIONS"] = "ALLOW-FROM http://foo.bar.com"
end
```

..and now it turns out that the client wants me to also whitelist `http://foo.dev.bar.com` as well.

I know that for setting X-FRAME-OPTIONS, the "ALLOW-FROM" option doesn't allow for multiple subdomains.  But since this is the same root domain with different subdomains, would it be a little more flexible?  For example, could I do something like

```
response.headers["X-FRAME-OPTIONS"] = "ALLOW-FROM http://*.bar.com"
```

as well?

Comment: possible duplicate of [X-Frame-Options Allow-From multiple domains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205192/x-frame-options-allow-from-multiple-domains)

Comment: I read that question, thank you very much.  It doesn't explain anything about Ruby on Rails, or what to do if you have two different subdomains of the same root domain.

Comment: I'm not trying to be argumentative when I say: your question isn't really Rails-specific, and the question/answer linked above does provide information on a wildcard prefix using `Content-Security-Policy`. Regardless, it seems `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` may not be the most forward-looking choice.

Comment: The question linked above makes it clear that `Content-Security-Policy` doesn't work in all browsers and that the relevant directive `frame-ancestors` only works in Chrome and Firefox. Also that answer's statements about `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` are out of date as well.

Answer (score 20):

You can use the `Content-Security-Policy` header instead, but it [doesn't work on everything](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy).

```
response.headers["X-Content-Security-Policy"] = "frame-ancestors http://*.bar.com";
response.headers["Content-Security-Policy"] = "frame-ancestors http://*.bar.com";
```

- `Content-Security-Policy` will override `X-Frame-Options` on modern browsers
- `X-Content-Security-Policy` will override `X-Frame-Options` on IE11

Comment: `frame-ancestors` is part of CSP version 2, which is [currently not supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=contentsecuritypolicy2) in Internet Explorer or Edge.

Comment: Note that frame-ancestors will not take priority in firefox, see this bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1024557 and upvote it to try get this fixed.

Comment: Per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP: _"sometimes you will see mentions of the X-Content-Security-Policy header, but that's an older version and you don't need to specify it anymore"_

Comment: Note: It is known that having both Content-Security-Policy and X-Content-Security-Policy or X-Webkit-CSP causes unexpected behaviours on certain versions of browsers. Please avoid using deprecated X-* headers.  - source:  https://content-security-policy.com/