# How to Prevent our website by Clickjacking in ASP.NET c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, clickjacking

I have a Dynamic website in which i have to make secure from clickjacking attack. In database getting these type of values while searching i was know little more about clickjacking but exactly is what not getting  so Please anyone who knows help me out.

Comment: Thomas is that the only way to protect from clickjacking attack. Just by adding global asax file and code.

Answer (score 90):

**X-FRAME-Options**

Add this code in global.asax file.

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("x-frame-options", "DENY");
}
```

**OR**

simply add this to `<system.webServer>` in your **Web.Config** file

```
<!--Clickjacking security-->
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <!--End clickjacking-->
```

This small snippet adds a http header called x-frame-options to your http responses and prevents your site being loaded in an iframe in "modern" browsers.
There are 3 values possible to X-Frame-Options:

1. **DENY**: do not allow any site to frame your application
2. **SAMEORIGIN**: only allow same application site to frame
3. **ALLOW-FROM**: only allow specific domain to frame your application

Comment: x-frame-options is deprecated and should be replaced with content-security-policy (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy). It seems that DENY still works fine in most browsers, but ALLOW-FROM is problematic.

Comment: @hotn Can you please provide the documentation as to the deprecation? MDN and other resources do not report this as deprecated.

Comment: @Itanex With my comment being over a year ago, I don't recall exactly where I read that. However, I have now found some conflicting info regarding x-frame-options. OWASP has documentation claiming its deprecation (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Limitations_2), while this SO answer implies that MDN documentation has changed since I commented (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25617678/764371).

Comment: @HotN Thanks for the links, that clears that up. Guess I will have to show this to my security team since they bugged my code for not implementing this. :)

Comment: Adding this line HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("x-frame-options", "DENY"); in global.asax add one more header with DENY when tested in postman. Do we first remove the header and add?

Answer (score 3):

Try [Best-for-now Legacy Browser Frame Breaking Script](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Clickjacking_Defense_Cheat_Sheet#Best-for-now_Legacy_Browser_Frame_Breaking_Script)

One way to defend against clickjacking is to include a "frame-breaker" script in each page that should not be framed. The following methodology will prevent a webpage from being framed even in legacy browsers, that do not support the X-Frame-Options-Header.

In the document HEAD element, add the following:

First apply an ID to the style element itself:

```
<style id="antiClickjack">body{display:none !important;}</style>
```

And then delete that style by its ID immediately after in the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   if (self === top) {
       var antiClickjack = document.getElementById("antiClickjack");
       antiClickjack.parentNode.removeChild(antiClickjack);
   } else {
       top.location = self.location;
   }
</script>
```

Comment: You could also add X-Frame-option into the Web.config, or use the way Musakkhir suggested.