# How to configure X-Frame-Options in Django to allow iframe embedding of one view?

Tags: django, iframe, http-headers, x-frame-options

I'm trying to enable django to allow one specific view to be embedded on external sites, preferabilly without sites restrictions.

In my *views.py* file, I have added the following code, where the view *futurebig* is the one I want to enable to be embedded:

```
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_sameorigin
...
@xframe_options_sameorigin
def futurebig(request):
    ...
    return render_to_response('templates/iframe/future_clock_big.html', context_dict, context)
```

which doesn't help as I understand because it only enables embedding in the same server.

How can I set the headers for that specific view to enable it to be embedded in any website?

For the record, I'm just a frontend developer, the backend developer who developed the site is no longer working with me and refused to document his code, so, If anyone could help me and explain carefully where and what modifications I should do, I'll apreciatte it very much.

Thanks.

As far as I know, the Django version is 1.6

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You are going in the right direction, but exact decorator which you will need to achieve this is 'xframe_options_exempt'.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.clickjacking import xframe_options_exempt

@xframe_options_exempt
def ok_to_load_in_a_frame(request):
    return HttpResponse("This page is safe to load in a frame on any site.")
```

PS: DJango 1.6 is no longer supported. It is good time to get an upgrade.

Comment: I think, we need decorator for ALLOW-FROM of iframe options https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options to define acceptable domains, not just remove X-Frame Header, please, somebody, create ticket (i have no access)

Answer (score 27):

Apparently you can set a rule in your settings telling the following:

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/'
```

Also nowadays you should consider moving to CSP

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' example.com *.example.net ;
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/25617678/186202

Comment: ALLOW-FROM  will not support chrome and safari

Comment: And ALLOW-FROM should NOT be used anymore: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options . As the @Natim said: Move to CSP!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to allow the frame in specific view you can add **Content-Security-Policy** to your view response, so your code will be something like this

```
def MyView(request):
    ....
    ....
    response = render(request,'MyViewHtml.html' ,{...})
    response ['Content-Security-Policy'] = "frame-ancestors 'self' https://example.com"
```