# How to allow Iframe to other website from Django Website?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, iframe, django-views

I am new to Django. I have launched a new site with Django. I wish people can iframe my site. But when doing I frame, It shows Site Refused to connect.
.
As a newbie,  I don’t have any idea what to do now. Would you please suggest me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33267383/how-to-configure-x-frame-options-in-django-to-allow-iframe-embedding-of-one-view

Answer (score 1):

Django 3.0(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/releases/3.0/#security) update disabled [X_FRAME_OPTIONS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/clickjacking/#setting-x-frame-options-for-all-responses) to DENY in settings.py. You can add the domain you want to show iframe in

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```