# Adding multiple domain/URL in Header set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM "

Tags: apache, http-headers, httpd.conf, x-frame-options, clickjacking

I want to add multiple domains/URL in Header set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM " (eg: Header set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM http://xyz, http://abc") in httpd.conf file . But I am unable to add 2 domains/URL as specified above. My requirement is the the X-Frame contents should be displayed only if the page is accessed from 2 different domains. So obviously I cannot give SAMEORGIN.  Please specify any alternate solutions to add 2 domains/URL in X-Frame-Options.

Comment: the format of that header does not allow to define several domains in one go, and it is not recognized by some browsers. You should use Access-Control-Allow-Origin instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [X-Frame-Options Allow-From multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205192/x-frame-options-allow-from-multiple-domains)

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your apache configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    Header set Content-Security-Policy "frame-ancestors http://*.example.com/ 'self';"

    # For IE 11 and below
    Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
    Header append X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM http://example.com/" </IfModule>
```