# How to allow multiple domains to use iframe from main domain on Nginx

Tags: nginx, iframe

I know very little about server configuration so excuse me if this is a silly question.  I have a site that hosts content for an iframe (mydomain.com) and I want to allow a couple of other sites to embed an iframe on their site of my content.  Initially, it was blocked so I read up on how to allow it using my nginx configuration on ubuntu digital ocean server but I could not find anything on allowing more than one domain.  When I try using the below directives it will throw console errors in firefox for not being allowed.  How do I allow more than one domain to use our content in an iframe?

This is what I tried:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://www.onedomain.com/";
add_header X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://www.anotherdomain.com/";
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";
```

The error code in the console shows:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.onedomain.com/ does not permit framing by https://www.anotherdomain.com/
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205192/x-frame-options-allow-from-multiple-domains

Comment: Possible duplicate of [X-Frame-Options Allow-From multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205192/x-frame-options-allow-from-multiple-domains)

Comment: @ShawnC. Both of these are specific to ASP.net, I am unable to make sense of the answers for my Nginx configuration using Ubuntu -- I will edit the question to specify I am running on Ubuntu

Comment: NGINX or ASP.net the browsers still follow RFC 7034 which states you can only have one Allow From. You can use Content-Security-Policy which allows multiple.

Comment: Thanks @ShawnC. I'm a total newbie to this, is there something specific I can look for or an example you can give?