# Load subdomains in iframes while avoiding cross-origin framing using document.domain

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, x-frame-options

I have a Wordpress multisite with multiple WooCommerce installations. I'm trying to get a dashboard report of all regions across the installation via iFrames:

- en.foo.com
- au.foo.com
- eu.foo.com

etc

On the main dashboard page, I'm using the following code to inject the required iFrames:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        /*If the user is on the main dashboard...*/
        if(window.location.href.indexOf("https://foo.com/wp-admin/network/") > -1) {
            console.log('Admin Dashboard - Activating global iFrame stats');
            /*Create area for iFrames*/
            $('#dashboard-widgets').after('<div class="iframe-container"><strong>Cross Network Stats (US, UK, AU, EU)</strong></div>');
            /*United States*/
            /*Add US iFrame (on same domain - working)*/
            $('.iframe-container').append('<div><strong style="font-size: 2em;">United States:</strong><br><br><iframe src="https://foo.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order" width="100%" height="450px"></iframe></div>');
            /*United Kingdom*/
            /*Add UK iFrame (on subdomain - not working)*/
            $('.iframe-container').append('<div><strong style="font-size: 2em;">United Kingdom:</strong><br><br><iframe src="https://en.foo.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order" width="100%" height="450px"></iframe></div>');
        }
    });
```

The first iFrame works as intended, however the second does not, as it's in an iFrame and creates an X-Frame security error:

---

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options:
>   https://en.foo.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order does not
>   permit cross-origin framing.

---

I have read that this can be avoided through use of 'document.domain'. As such I've injected the following code into my footer on the global admin footer:

```
echo '<script>document.domain = "foo.com";</script>';
```

However, I am still getting the same issue as before.

Do I need to trigger document.domain as a javascript function while calling the iFrames via jQuery?

Comment: Haven't dealt with `document.domain` for a long time and it can be tricky....if it still even works. Always had to declare it immediately...before everything else. Might also read up on X-Frame-Options

Comment: Thanks, I've placed the script above all the others but still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your `Content-Security-Policy` header.

`Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' *.foo.com`

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25617678/8781351) goes a bit more in depth.

Comment: Tried adding to my apache2.conf file (in Ubuntu) and get the following: "AH00526: Syntax error on line 204 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Invalid command 'Content-Security-Policy:', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration". I'm assuming I'm doing this wong...

Comment: I don't actually know anything about headers in Apache. That was just the "standard " notation for headers, the syntax for Apache is probably different.