# X-Frame-Option configuration not working in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have made X-Frame-Option as SameOrigin. But Still I can able to render the same document in IFrame from different origin.

Answer (score 0):

a lack of informations about project, versions etc..

Please provide some code example

Anyway did you try [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) ?

Answer (score 0):

First, the correct header name is `X-Frame-Options` and not `X-Frame-Option`

Please read the [Security#default-headers](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/security.html#default-headers) to understand how to change the defaults headers, the `X-Frame-Options` including.

Given you want to change the `X-Frame-Options` by in a controller, you can use something like:

```rb
class MyAwesomeController < ApplicationController
  def show
    response.headers["X-FRAME-OPTIONS"] = "ALLOW-FROM http://mysite"
  end
end
```

After all, take a time to read about `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` vs `Frame-Ancestors`, `X-FRAME-OPTIONS` seems deprecated in some browsers. A good read can start in this discussion [X-Frame-Options Allow-From multiple domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205192/x-frame-options-allow-from-multiple-domains/25617678#25617678)