# HttpModule and Page creation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HTTPModule Event Execution Order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441421/httpmodule-event-execution-order)

I'm investigating where does the Page object is initially created  in the HttpModule Pipeline :

```
 HttpModule 

     ===========
    #1  BeginRequest
    #2  AuthenticateRequest
    #3  AuthorizeRequest
    #4  RespolveRequestCache
    #5  AcquireRequestState 
    #6  PreRequestHandnlerExecute

    Handler
    ========
    #7  ProcessRequest

   ... later stages
   ================
```

and here is my expirament :

I've register each function to execute a specific method  :

```
  void check(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          Page objPage = (sender as HttpApplication).Context.Handler as Page;
          if (objPage == null) return;
          ...
        }
```

the *first* stage where the "safe cast" worked successfully  was the `AcquireRequestState` .

Question :

It did worked for *me*  , but is it a safe place to acquire the page class ?

Also , why isn't it documented anywhere ? I've searched in Msdn in what stage the page class is first accessible , and couldn't find any.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov did you _read_ my question at all ? I don't see in the duplicated question any mention for _when_ page is crated. Please notice .

Comment: I think second one give you the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx) which says it happens during MapRequestHandler on step 10: "The handler can be a native-code module such as the IIS 7.0 StaticFileModule or a managed-code module such as the PageHandlerFactory "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's created between the [PostResolveRequestCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postresolverequestcache.aspx) and [AcquireRequestState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.acquirerequeststate.aspx)

From the top of my head, I think that [PostAcquireRequestState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postacquirerequeststate.aspx) would be safer to access the page

> Occurs when the request state (for example, session state) that is associated with the current request has been obtained.

Comment: yeah you right http://books.google.co.il/books?id=2wg5LCKuChcC&pg=PA189&lpg=PA189&dq=%22for+a+web+form+request,+this+is+the+point+when+the+page+is+compiled%22&source=bl&ots=HjwehFyeIJ&sig=A9Myhuxp7ioo4q2MRAkhCRNFiHM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ALZmUKenEq_S4QTIo4G4Dw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22for%20a%20web%20form%20request%2C%20this%20is%20the%20point%20when%20the%20page%20is%20compiled%22&f=false. I had to find it in my book. why doesn't msdn state it ?

Comment: I remember I read it somewhere in the extensive MSDN documentation, cannot find it though...