# Is Application_AuthenticateRequest always before Session_Start?

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-6, global-asax

Does Application_AuthenticateRequest always fire before Session_Start in global.asax? I'm trying to find some authoritative documentation regarding it.

I assume it does, and researching it suggests it does. But I've not found an authoritative answer (unless I'm missing something).

My normal resource for the [asp.net application lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is nicely detailed, but doesn't really go into detail how some of modules' events are ordered.

Does anyone know of some authoritative documentation that details examples of how some of the built in modules events are ordered (particularly the SessionStateModule)?

I've hunted around, but not found anything yet.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441421/httpmodule-event-execution-order/441460#441460

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I haven't seen any official documentation, but looking at the `SessionStateModule` in Reflector shows that the `Start` event is raised by the `RaiseOnStart` method, which is called from the `CompleteAcquireState` method, which is called from the `BeginAcquireState` method, which handles the `AcquireRequestState` event.

According to the [application lifecycle page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the `AcquireRequestState` event is always raised after the `AuthenticateRequest`, `AuthorizeRequest`, `ResolveRequestCache` and `PostMapRequestHandler` events.

**NB:** This is for .NET 4.0, but I believe the same is true for previous versions as well.

Comment: Goodol' Reflector! Thanks Richard for spending the time digging into the code.