# Datetime Parameter Report Builder

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am using Report builder. Is there any ways to display the date of datetime parameter in dd-MMM-yyyy ( 1-Mar-2017) format?

Comment: Do you mean you want to the date format in the date picker to match that?

Comment: Yes, that is the format i want to use in the date picker

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38202281/change-datetime-format-in-date-picker-ssrs

Comment: thanks for reply! However, I can't find the (1-Mar-2017) format after i deployed it.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server's `CONVERT()` function should be able to handle this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, date, 106) AS date_formatted
FROM yourTable
```

Here `date` is the column containing dates which you want to format as you specified in your question.